# Retrieving all usernames from a tweet in a PHP function

Tags: php, function, twitter, preg-match-all, hashtag

I have this function, which color every @username contained in a string

```
 //color  @username
 function hashtag_links($string,$id_session) {
 preg_match_all('/@(\w+)/',$string,$matches);
 foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
$string = str_replace("@$match", "<span class=color>@$match</span>", "$string");
 }
 return $string;
 }
```

Everything is good while the usernames are different (@cat,@pencil,@scubadiving), but in case the username starts with the same letters (@cat,@caterpiller,@cattering), the functions only colors the repeated letters in this case (@cat), what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use preg_replace instead:

```
//color  @username
function hashtag_links($string,$id_session) {
    return preg_replace('/@(\w+)/', '<span class=color>@$1</span>', $string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... assuming you have a string like this:

```
$string='Hey there, folks! @bob, @kevin, @bobby, @keverino';
```

I would try something like:

```
preg_replace('/(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)/','<span style="color:pink;">\1</span>',$string);
```

Of course, I don't know what your usernames can contain, so you might have to adjust the regex.